# Узнать расположение файла по его процессу | C#

Tags: c#, windows

По заголовку собственно уже думаю понятно, что хотелось бы уточнить, как лучше брать путь к запущенному файлу. )

Comment: Нет, к сожалению, не понятно. ОС какая? Вы хотите узнать путь к _своему_ файлу или к исполняемому файлу какого-то другого процесса? Если другого, то что про него известно?

Comment: OS Windows. То есть, имеется исполняемый файл, допустим calc.exe и я не знаю где он находится. но этот файла в данный момент запущен и висит в процессах. Как по этому процессу узнать расположенме файла. )

Comment: Так что Вы знаете об этом разыскиваемом файле? Имя процесса?

Comment: Да, только имя процесса.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
using System.Diagnostics;

Process[] processlist = Process.GetProcessesByName("calc");

String result = ":(";
foreach(Process p in processlist)
{
    try
    {
        result = p.MainModule.FileName;
        break;
    }
    catch (Win32Exception)
    {
    }
}

System.Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Comment: Только маленькая поправка: вместо просмотра всех процессов лучше найти список процессов по имени: foreach (Process process in Process.GetProcessesByName("calc"))

Comment: Спасибо большое. Сейчас попробую. :)

Comment: Да, я уже заметил ). Спасибо.

Comment: @Eugene только вот я не знаю, как решить проблему с 64-битностью… Похоже, никак.

Comment: Мне 32 надо. ) Просто надо делать на 10 машинах обновление файла одного. И делать это на каждой машине отдельно - ломает. решил автоматизировать. )

Comment: @Eugene Проблема будет, если не сойдётся битность у Вашего C#-приложения у процесса, который ищете. У меня так и не получилось найти у себя адрес Калькулятора, поскольку Калькулятор-то 64-битный, а Студия по-умолчанию собирает 32-битный exe'шник.

Comment: Ооо... так это серьёзный косяк..

Comment: Выход только один: написать багрепорт группе, разрабатывающей ядро Винды ;). Это «by design»: 32-битные процессы никак не могут взаимодействовать с 64-битными.

Comment: Кстати, похоже наоборот тоже нельзя. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.modules.aspx   тут предлагают использовать EnumProcessModulesEx, как workaround.

Comment: А в чем проблема на Powershell написать?
Или батником?
Путь не может быть статическим к приложению?
Если он постоянно один то можно PsExec использовать для автоматизации

Answer (score 3):

```
Process.MainModule.FileName
```

Единственный нюанс - из х86 приложения не получится получить доступ к `MainModule` х64 приложения.

Answer (score 0):

ProcessImageFileName.