# Как узнать путь к файлу по имени процесса и имени владельца?

Tags: windows, c#, процесс

На терминальном сервере человек 10 запускают приложение, пусть это будет CALC.exe, и естетсвенно, в процессах 10 ОДИНАКОВЫХ процессов.

[Здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/2938/%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%86%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%81%D1%83-c) мне подсказали, как узнать путь к файлу нужного процесса.

А как сделать тоже самое, только если пользователя зовут ВАСЯ, то процесс запущенный ВАСЕЙ и находился?

Comment: В следующий раз, пожалуйста, формулируйте сразу вопрос целиком. А то ведь не всякое решение задачи малыми жертвами допиливается до решения более сложной.

Comment: @Eugene Не забывайте, пожалуйста, принимать (галочка) лучший ответ на вопрос.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Самый простой вариант с помощью WMI:

```
string processName = "calc.exe";
string currentUser = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name.Split('\\')[1];

string query = "Select * from Win32_Process Where Name = \"" + processName + "\"";
ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(query);
ManagementObjectCollection processes = searcher.Get();

foreach (ManagementObject proc in processes)
{
    string owner;
    string[] argList = new string[] { string.Empty };
    int returnVal = Convert.ToInt32(proc.InvokeMethod("GetOwner", argList));
    if (returnVal == 0)
        owner = argList[0];
    else
        continue;

    if (owner != currentUser)
        continue;

    // Вот тут-то и остался только нужный процесс!
    string path = proc["ExecutablePath"].ToString();
}
```

Comment: Кстати! Как же я ещё тогда не подумал про WMI. Поскольку тут нет непосредственно взаимодействия между процессами, этому способу глубоко по барабану битность.

Answer (score 3):

На WinApi проблема решалась еще в первом вопросе)
Поиск по msdn выдал сразу:

Получаем токен процесса по хендлу: [OpenProcessToken(...)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa379295(v=vs.85).aspx)

SID пользователя - в информации о токене: [GetTokenInformation(...)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446671(v=vs.85).aspx)

---

@kirelagin:

Оригинал с мсдн:

```
BOOL WINAPI OpenProcessToken(
  __in   HANDLE ProcessHandle,
  __in   DWORD DesiredAccess,
  __out  PHANDLE TokenHandle
);
```

В c#:

```
[DllImport("Advapi32.dll", EntryPoint = "OpenProcessToken")]
private static extern bool OpenProcessToken(int ProcessHandle, int DesiredAccess, int* TokenHandle);
```

Comment: К сожалению, WinAPI в C# довольно непросто вкрутить :(.