# Проверка запущен ли процесс? C#

Tags: c#

Запускал процесс через proc.Start(), как проверить запущен ли этот процесс?

Comment: Сначала процесс(-ы) нужно [найти](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/2938/%D0%A3%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%86%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%81%D1%83-c) затем его(их) нужно [убить](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/615032/%D0%A3%D0%B1%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%86%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%81-%D0%B2-c). С какой частью у Вас возникли сложности?

Comment: Мне нужно процесс закрыть именно по его расположению, потому что есть идентичные названия

Comment: У Вас тут два вопроса: как найти и как убить. Сконцентрируйтесь на одном. По поводу расположения: поищите по названию, пройдитесь по всем найденным процессам и проверьте совпадает ли расположение. Как найти полный путь вроде уже ответили: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/2938/%D0%A3%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%86%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%81%D1%83-c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Находите все процессы, получайте ID, и PATH, процесса  - если путь совпадает, убиваете процесс по ID.

Comment: Можно пример из кода?